# Own Iterator doesn't work

Tags: c++, iterator

I work on own `iterator`, that should iterate double linked list. If I'm iterating, for cycle is immediately skipped. I haven't errors, but from debugging I don't read much.

**`for` cycle:**

```
for(SemestralWork::DoubleList<Student>::iterator it = link->begin(); it != link->end(); ++it){
         //something...
    }
```

**`iterator` + `begin()` + `end()`:**

```
class iterator {
private:
    Node<T> * node;
public:
    iterator(){}
    iterator(const iterator& cit){}
    iterator(T t) {

    }
    ~iterator(){}

    iterator& operator=(const iterator& second){
        node = second.node;
        return(*this);
    }
    iterator& operator++(){     
        if (node != NULL){
            node = node->GetNext();
        }
        return(*this);
    }
    iterator operator++(int){
        iterator tmp = *this;   //iterator tmp(*this)
        operator++();
        return tmp;
    }
    bool operator==(const iterator& second) {
        return node == second.node;
    }
    bool operator!=(const iterator& second) {
        return node != second.node;
    }
    T& operator*() {return node->GetData();}
    T* operator->(){return((DoubleList<T>::iterator)*this);} 
};

iterator begin(){
    return iterator(first->GetData());
}

iterator end(){
    return iterator(last->GetData());
}
```

**`Node`:**

```
template <class U>
    class Node{
        Node<U> * next;
        Node<U> * previous;
        U data;
    public:
        Node(const U &data){
            next = NULL;
            previous = NULL;
            this->data = data;
        }
        void SetNext(Node<U> *next) { this->next = next; }
        Node<U> *GetNext(){ return next; }
        void SetPrevious(Node<U> *previous) { this->previous = previous; }
        Node<U> *GetPrevious(){ return previous; }
        U &GetData() { return data; }
    };
```

Comment: Do you have any reason for not using the std::list? It is already double linked list with iterators.

Comment: It's my semester work, I can't :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few things I noticed. Whether any of these will actually resolve your problem I don't know because the posted code is incomplete:

1. Your `iterator` should *not* be constructed from a `T` object and the implementation of the constructor should actually do something (I would guesss the fact that `iterator::iterator(T)` doesn't do anything at all is your actual problem). Instead, the `iterator` should be constructed from an `Node<T>*`.
2. The preincrement operator should *not* check if there is actually a next element! It is a precondition for the `operator++()` that the iterator can be incremented. If anything, the operator should report a misuse with debug settings enabled.
3. I'm suspicious of your use of `last`: note that the end iterator is a position one *past* the last element.
4. Your comparision oerators should be `const` members and typically `operator!=()` just delegates to `operator==()`, i.e.:

   ```
   bool iterator::operator!=(iterator const& other) const {
       return !(*this == other);
   }
   ```

   The advantage of this implementation is that the `operator!=()` is consistent with the `operator==()` even if the implementation of `operator==()` is changed.

Comment: Uh, more problems then I expected :D ad1: If i create next constructor   like `iterator(Prvek<T> * iter) : prvek(iter){}` then `iterator begin()` doesn't know this constructor, but why?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the list implementation showing `first` and `last`, but I'm assuming `last` points at the last element. With iterators, `end()` should point *beyond* the last element, not *to* the last element. For example, if the list contains exactly 1 element, your for-loop won't run at all since `first == last` and therefore `begin() == end()`.

Comment: I see, ok. So I have to use e.g. `iterator end(){ return(iterator(NULL)); }` right?

Comment: Yep, that would work, as long as `++it` on an iterator pointing to your last element advances to `end()`. It is an error to dereference an `end()` iterator so you need not worry about that.